# Section title gets too long in header

Tags: header-footer, section-titles

On page 9 of the generated document, you can see that the section title is so long that is gets on two lines and overrides the chapter title.
In some programming languages, I would think of including some kind of "truncate" version in my header definition.
I also read things about having shorter versions of chapter/section title, (something like \sectionmark) , but this was not recognised by my compiler.

What would be a way to have a shorter title in header.

Code:
**Main.tex**

```
    %Preamble
    \documentclass[a4paper,french,oneside,openright]{book}

    \usepackage{afterpage}
    \newcommand{\blankpage}{
        \null
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \addtocounter{page}{-1}
        \newpage
        }
        
    \usepackage[french]{babel}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \usepackage{tocloft,calc}
    \renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }
    \AtBeginDocument{\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\widthof{\bfseries Chapter }}}


    \title{Title}
    \author{Name}
    \date{2020}

    \begin{document}
        \input{Pages/TitlePage.tex}
        \input{Pages/Thanks.tex}


        \tableofcontents

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{Title}
\rfoot{Page \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[L]{Title}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Line at the header invisible
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt}% Line at the footer visible
}

        \chapter{Introduction}
            \section{Introduction}
            \lipsum
        \chapter{Chapter title}
            \section{This section title is toooooooooooooooooooooooooooo long}
            \lipsum
        \chapter{Chapter title}
            \section{SectionTitle}
            \lipsum
        \chapter{Chapter title}
            \section{SectionTitle}
            \lipsum
        \chapter{Chapter title}
            \section{SectionTitle}
            \lipsum
        \chapter{Chapter title}
            \section{SectionTitle}
            \lipsum
        \chapter{Chapter title}
            %\section{SectionTitle}  %Testing what happens in table of contents when there is a chapter without section.
            \lipsum
        \chapter{Chapter title}
            \section{SectionTitle}
            \lipsum
    \end{document}
```

**Pages\TitlePage.tex**

```
\begin{titlepage}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\HRule \\[0.9cm]
\begin{center}
    \textsc{\Huge Title}\\[1cm]
    \textsc{\LARGE Subtitle}\\[1.5cm]
\end{center}
\HRule \\[1.5cm]

\begin{center} \Large
    \begin{tabular}{ l r }  
        \emph{Text} & Text\\ 
        \emph{Text} & Text
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\vfill

\begin{center} \large
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l r @{}}
        \ Text & Text\\
        \ Text & Text\\
        \ Text & Text\\
        \ Text & Text\\
        \ Text & Text
    \end{tabular*}
\end{center}
\afterpage{\blankpage}
\end{titlepage}
```

**Pages\Thanks.tex**

```
\pagestyle{empty}
\part*{Thanks}
\blankpage
```

Comment: You can use the optional argument of \section to define a short version for the header.(and the table of contents).

Comment: Thanks I didn't know you could write this: \section[test]{Section 4}

Comment: Hello, I back working on this document ... I notice 2 problems with this solution:
I get titles overlapping on two lines ... I truncate what I think would be enough from section optional name, then both titles get condense on one single line. And I come to situations where I cannot have a single word in my section name without overlapping the chaptername.
Hence I tried removed the shortened title like this: \section[]{Section X title} ... but then my sections don't have a title in my table of content... I don"t think that the shortened title should be impacting the table of content at all...

Comment: I found a solution to this new problem here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343188/fancyhdr-chapter-and-section-titles-overlap-when-titles-are-long

Comment: @TTT -- This sounds like a candidate for closing as a duplicate.  Do you agree?

Comment: @barbarabeeton : Sorry, this is a bit old for me to remember everything very precisely, but if I wrote that the linked question solves the "new" problem, I likely meant that it did not solve the initial problem. I guess that my solution was a combination of Bernard's answer and of the linked answer. So no, it doesn't seem like a duplicate.

Comment: @TTT -- Thanks for following up.