# Wrong hyphenation of long subsection titles in the toc and the title itself

Tags: table-of-contents, hyphenation, subsection

It seems that Latex has a problem with the correct hyphenation of very long, one word (sub-)section titles in the title itself and the toc.
With the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,
           top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]
           {geometry}
\usepackage{sectsty,ragged2e}
\allsectionsfont{\RaggedRight}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section}

\subsection{(5\textit{R},6\textit{E},8\textit{E})-5-[(2-methoxyethoxy)methoxy]-\textit{N}-methoxy-\textit{N}-methyldeca-6,8-dienamid}


\end{document}
```

i end up with overfull hboxes in the toc and the title of the subsection.

[image]

Is there any way to prevent this mess?

Comment: Possible related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343188/fancyhdr-chapter-and-section-titles-overlap-when-titles-are-long

Comment: Since the "very long word" is the IUPAC name of a chemical, you may want to take a look at the `\iupac` command provided by the `\chemmacros` package. You may also be interested in using its `\cip` command  in order to avoid using `\textit{R}` over and over.

Comment: This is a situation where it would seem best to set these headings ragged right, and avoid additional word-hyphenation altogether.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the `\iupac` command from `chemmacros`:

[image]

(Red lines indicate the margins.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,
           top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]
           {geometry}
\usepackage{sectsty,ragged2e}
\allsectionsfont{\RaggedRight}
\usepackage{chemmacros}



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Sectionn}    

\subsection{\iupac{\cip{5R,6E,8E}-5-[(2-methoxyethoxy)methoxy]-\N-methoxy-\N-methyldeca-6,8-di|enamid}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This comes very close to what I am looking for but it appears to me that the hyphenation is sometimes a little bit odd (even tough grammatically correct). I think it would be a little bit better if latex wouldnt use the whole textwidth given by breaking the line in the middle of word but adding a linebreak at one of the "-".

Comment: I'm unable to test, but it seems to me that setting `\hyphenpenalty` quite high and `\exhyphenpenalty` quite low, even slightly negative, might encourage line breaking preferentially at the existing hyphens.  `\Raggedright` is definitely a good thing here.

Answer (score 0):

`polish.sty` rules!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,
           top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]
           {geometry}
\usepackage{sectsty,ragged2e}
\usepackage{polski}
\allsectionsfont{\RaggedRight}


\begin{document}

\overfullrule5pt
\tableofcontents
\section{Section}

\subsection{(5\textit{R},6\textit{E},8\textit{E})-5-[(2-methoxyethoxy)methoxy]-\textit{N}-methoxy-\textit{N}-methyldeca-6,8-dienamid}

And the solution:  

\subsection{(5\textit{R},6\textit{E},8\textit{E})\dywiz5\dywiz[(2\dywiz{}methoxyethoxy)methoxy]\dywiz\textit{N}\dywiz{}methoxy\dywiz\textit{N}\dywiz{}methyldeca\dywiz6,8\dywiz{}dienamid}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To tell the truth, it is enough only to extract `\dywiz` from `polish.sty`, defined as
`\def\dywiz{\kern0sp\discretionary{-}{-}{-}\penalty10000\hskip0sp\relax}`.